# PR2 upgrade, sources http://packages.willowgarage.com

Tags: ros, pr2, packages, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just wanted to update - upgrade the robot (with the usual `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`) within the robot. Nonetheless it cannot be done since the robot cannot connect to "http://packages.willowgarage.com" it seems the server has been down since some time already (I tried last week too). Anyone has any workaround this?

In my source files **there is no packages.willowgarage.com**. So I don't know who is calling this server. I copy the files next.

In my *source.list* file:

```
# deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

# deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
# deb http:///ubuntu precise-security main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb-src http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb-src http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
deb-src http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb-src http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://aptproxy.willowgarage.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse



## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

And in my */etc/apt/sources.list.d/* directory I have 3 files (pr2debs.list  pr2debspr2.list  rosdebs.list) and the mix of all is :

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/pr2/ubuntu precise main
deb http://packages.ros.org/pr2/ubuntu precise pr2
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143986/pr2-upgrade,-sources-http://packages.willowgarage.com/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The sources files for PR2 repository are in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

When the ROS packages site moved to OSUOSL last year, Willow lost the ability to update the PR2 repositories hosted there, so the PR2 packages were moved to packages.willowgarage.com, and a redirect was set up to redirect clients from packages.ros.org/pr2 to packages.willowgarage.com/pr2 .

I'm not quite sure what has happened since then, but it looks like redirect is still in place, redirecting you from packages.ros.org/pr2 to packages.willowgarage.com/pr2, and packages.willowgarage.com is offline, which is causing the error you're seeing.

You should contact the PR2 support team directly about this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1